# I want to clear symbol "-" with previous Digit

Tags: android

I/p: 1234-4
I want: (if I press keyboard back button) O/p: 1)  1234-, 2) if I press again then 0/p should be: 123, but I am getting 1234.

```java
 @Override  
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        nikId.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                    keyDel = 1;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (keyDel == 0) {
            int len = nikId.getText().length();
            if(len == 4 || len==9 || len==14) {
                nikId.setText(nikId.getText()+ "-");
                nikId.setSelection(nikId.getText().length());
            }
        } else {
            keyDel = 0;
        }

    }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by I/p and O/p ?

Comment: Please replace "-" to blank space so it will solve your issue.
String data= string.replace("-", "");

Comment: if i click keyboard clear button it should  clear the '-" with its pervious digit.